# How to center values in boxvalues for shiny/flexdashboard?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have these box values here at the top of my dashboard. I want to center align the title and the value.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to reproduce your example, I used a shinydashboard skeleton, I put the `infobox` inside a `column()` that was inside a `fluidRow`. The trick was adding *`width = 3,align="center"`* in the column.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(fluidRow(
    # A static infoBox
   column( infoBox("New Orders", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card")), width = 3,align="center"),

    ),)
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

- Which centered my infobox

[image]

To render this in a `Rmd` file just use this

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Daniel"
date: "5/6/2021"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(fluidRow(
    # A static infoBox
   column( infoBox("New Orders", 10 * 2, icon =     icon("credit-card")), width = 3,align="center"),

    ),)
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```
````

You have to zoom into the Rmarkdown file shiny window for the responsive effect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, is this written in a chunk or in the top area of the markdown file?

Comment: You can just save this as a regular R file, and RStudio will know it's a shiny app

Comment: I updated my answer to show it in a Rmarkdown file.